# UIPopoverController orientation crash in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, ios6

My current program only support landscape orientation.

In iOS 6, it crash on `UIPopoverController`.

> 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

I enable all orientation for project , it's working well. However, I need to change a lot for all of the views to only support landscape.

Is there other easy way to fix , `UIOrientation` in `UIPopoverController` ?

Comment: Hi @satungod, my answer was unfortunately delete by a moderator because I had already posted it on another thread... fair enough. Please find this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12575058/662605 - I'm adding a new answer to direct to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `UIApplicationDelegate`:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

You can still set your supported interface orientations in your `Info.plist` file and by returning a mask in each view controller's `supportedInterfaceOrientations:` method.

Comment: This is correct, as per https://devforums.apple.com/message/731764#731764

Answer (score 0):

New a subclass of UIImagePickerController and add this codes:

```
@property (nonatomic)NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations;

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return _supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
    if (imagePickerController==nil) {
        imagePickerController = [[WUIImagePickerController alloc]init];//the subclass
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;//any orientation you want to set
        if (popoverController==nil) {
            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
        }
    }
```

Who knows a better way please tell me.

Comment: Take a look at Daniel's answer. There is a link with an answer.

Comment: this is not a setter method

        imagePickerController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;

totally wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Thy this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600082/set-orientation-to-landscape-mode-in-xcode-4-5-gm-ios-6). You have to set your application to support all orientations at the start. Do the change in app delegate.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window

{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else  /* iphone */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

Use Above Code, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use these delegates for orientation,
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```