# UIApplication invalid interface orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

My application is in Landscape mode and in the application user has to register with photo whenever he clicks on browse button it directs to camera roll ,but when i am clicking on browse action an exception is occuring.
Below is the Exception what i got

```
'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your desired interface from the summary tab of the application -> supported Interface Orientation.

[image]

Comment: what code you have in - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation method?

Comment: I used these methods -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
} and here it works fine,but without attaching image it moves to mainviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Look at this url for help regarding all the orientation related problems

**['Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456879/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shou)**

Comment: here it will change to potrait know but it should not change to potrait

Comment: are you setting orientation properties for the imagepickercontroller? in that case it will cause some problem related to orientaion

Comment: you can either use this for reference.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737632/open-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-mode