# why i have this showAlert error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need block a screen. im using the next fuctions:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
}
```

but the problem is that i have a show alert function,

```
func showAlert(message: String) {
    self.viewUtils.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))


    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //activity.hidden = true
}
```

and when i call it i see the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception

> 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [UIAlertController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following links and based on this you can change in your code. Please search before asking question.

1. [iOS 8.3 supported orientations crashs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629106/ios-8-3-supported-orientations-crashs)
2. ['Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456879/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shou)
3. [Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul)

Answer (score 0):

Your `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method implementation looks wrong. Try changing it to something like the following:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```