# App Crashing in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

App is crashing when I use `UIImagePicker` on iPhone, but only on *iOS 7*.
I use the following code lines

```
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
    {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    } else {
        //[self showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Your Device Don't Have Camera"];
    }

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The app is running on iOS 6, not in iOS 7.
I am new on this site, please help.

Comment: Can you post the exception you're getting?

Comment: To make it clear. It crashes when running under `iOS 7` and works under `iOS 6`? Yeah best way is to also post the error message etc. from the console.

Comment: reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Comment: then in to your ViewController shouldAutorotate change to NO instead of YES.

Comment: tried but no luck. app is running in iOS6,not in iOS 7.

Comment: @Pravin, Is there your app in Landscape mode?

Comment: Yes,app is in Landscape mode.

Comment: @Pravin, Waitt!! I am uploading my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerController` presenting in `Potratin` Mode Only in iPhone. And i found one more bug in to your Code that you are using `picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` while `isCameraDeviceAvailable` that wrong:-

you should code like:-

```
if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
    {
       picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
         picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                 [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];       
    }
```

and in to your ViewController `shouldAutorotate` change to NO instead of YES

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer. Seems this answer solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

**In you ViewController.m file before start @implementation write following code**

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

**Where you want to create a object of Image Picker write following code**

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self; 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: PopOverController Works on iPhone?

Comment: @Pravin, oh sorry... Wait a minute.. I am updating my answer.

Comment: solved, but in iphone popup is opening in portraid mode..but i need ladscape mode.

Comment: imager Picker is never support the Landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

ok if that is the case try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul) out...

add this to your ViewController

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     //Because your app is only landscape, your view controller for the view in your
     // popover needs to support only landscape
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: I think this is deprecated now. Only Navigation controllers are supposed to have supportedInterfaceOrientations method