# SKStoreProductViewController crashes on iphone iOS 7 landscape app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7, landscape-portrait

I have a universal landscape mode app.   SKStoreProductViewController works fine on iPad.  But crashes on iphone ios 7.   Even I set the SKStoreProductViewController to display on portrait on iPhone.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       NSLog(@"iphone portrait");
       return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
   }
   else
       return [super preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

The SKStoreProductViewController shows on portrait on iphone iOS 7, but when I rotate the phone, it crashes.  I got error message says:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Anyone knows how to solve the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul   ?

Answer (score 10):

You want should autorotate to return NO if the application and the ViewController have no common interface orientations. Here's my solution:

Subclass SKStoreProductViewController and override -shouldAutorotate with the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask applicationSupportedOrientations = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask viewControllerSupportedOrientations = [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    return viewControllerSupportedOrientations & applicationSupportedOrientations;
}
```

Comment: SKStoreProductViewController don't work correctly in iOS 11 / iOS 12  on landscape mode with support orientations :O