# Supported orientations Crash iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

I have portrait only app which do video capturing and some other tasks! everything is working fine, I want to keep app in portrait, but Camera view in landscape only. I have rotated single view test in portrait app by using `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` but Rotating Camera view caused the Following Crash:

```
Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```

for further info I m using following line to insert show camera. I insert camera view only when app is in landscape. I use following line of code to show camera!

```
[self.view insertSubview:imagePicker.view atIndex:0];
```

any solution/suggestion please?

Comment: Take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul

Comment: @BoranA First two high votes solutions did not worked on iOS 7, comments underneath 3rd solutions are before iOS 7. (headbang) :(

Comment: :) What is your root view controller?

Comment: I m using JASidepanel! center view, I push a view, and then insert camera screen view as mention above code, if I make presentModalViewController it works fine, but camera view do not go in landscape. :(

Comment: Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

Comment: This is from picker controller's class reference.

Comment: 100% true and I have read this already! if you open a native camera and rotate the device, controls are rotated. If I add UIImagePicker as a subview, it gets rotated but if I add it as presentModalViewController it do not get rotated :(

Answer (score 0):

First change your orientation settings to support landscape and portrait. Create a `UINavigationController` category and add this lines. (I assume that your center view controller is a navigation controller)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and present your image picker.

Edit: In iOS7 this method is not working. I guess the only proper way is creating a layer for camera controls and subclass uiimagepickerview to support landscape only.

Comment: Already did this, Camera controls are not showing in Landscape :(