# UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation exception occurring when tapping the emoji icon in the iOS8.3 keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I am receiving the following exception in one of my viewControllers (when tapping the emoji icon in the keyboard):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported
>   orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   [_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning
>   YES'

Anyone know of a fix for this? My app is exclusively portrait mode (set in the 'General' settings panel in XCode 6.3).

There is no particular line that it crashes at, it appears to be OS code that is causing it.

This problem started occurring after the recent iOS8.3 update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul.