# How to use UIImagePicker with landscapeRight mode only?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

### I have some problem with UIImagePicker with my controller . first I set up my controller support with landscapeRight only and then I add UIImagePicker to my controller and it show error like this .

### Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

please help . Thank you.

Comment: check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul)

Comment: I can't find a good solution code with swift 3 . bro

Comment: you know you can convert objective C code to Swift, right ?

Comment: yes bro . thank you for your help

Comment: Convert [here](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/)

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: I have other problem with Image . When I convert image to base64 and than I covert base64 back to image . it's show wrong rotation. Could you help me ?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {
   let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let strBase64 = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: 
       .lineLength64Characters)
   return strBase64!
    }

func convertBase64ToImage(base64String: String) -> UIImage {
     let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, 
         options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
return decodedimage!
        
    }

Comment: wrong rotation as in @Mr Ice

Comment: i did not get any errors ?

Comment: I don't know why ? first I convert to base64 and then I convert it back to Image and show it in ImageView  the result of image rotate don't like before convert .

Comment: can you add a screenShot @Mr Ice

Comment: ok . I'll post this problem .thz bro