# UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation error on IPhone X during UIImagePickerController presenting in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-x

I have `MainViewController` in landscapeRight orientation which should present `UIImagePickerController with sourceType = .camera:`

```
imagePickerCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
imagePickerCamera.allowsEditing = false
self.present(imagePickerCamera, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

App crashes and then the error says (only on IPhone X):

> *'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and
>   [CAMViewfinderViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'*

I have set supported orientation in AppDelegate to .landscapeRight.
I've tried to set all orientation in .plist and app delegate and only then show imagePicker, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I saw some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul) but it didn't help me too.

**I found an workaround**, but it's doesn't seems like a good solution. You need to set portrait orientation (or just supportedOrientation through supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor), then present picker and when you're done switch back to landscape if needed.

Also I saw somewhere an article in Apple documentation which says that UIImagePickerController supports only Portrait orientation, but I've been using landscape with the image/camera picker for a long time, so idk.

Comment: Most probably you just mess the presentation and dismissal of controllers, for example you are presenting VC on some already dismissing controller.

Comment: @MarekStaňa not sure if it's possible with rootViewController

Comment: Same issue I am facing right now, My app is in landscape and mode, when I open a camera , I have to set orientation portrait. On dismiss, I have to set landscape. Which is not a good solution. If you find anything, Kindly update us (Y).