# PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController in Landscape causes Exception

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, applepay, passkit

I'm trying to present a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController in a Landscape only application. Is this really not possible? I keep getting an the exception below.

'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540597/supported-orientations-has-no-common-orientation-with-the-application-and-shoul

Comment: It is not possible. In order for FaceID to work correctly the device must be in a portrait orientation