# presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated crashing in iOS 6.0

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I just upgraded from iOS 5.1.1 to 6.0 and the following code path is crashing with SIGTRAP when it attempts to display a popover with an imagePickerViewController as its contentVC to allow the user to select an image or video from the photoLibrary.

It was working great with 5.1.1. I've been troubleshooting this for a couple of days with no headway.
Does anyone have a handle on this? Is there an alternative method to use for iOS6.0? I can add more code if needed...

I can capture images and video with the line:

```
[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Here is the method in full called after the user touches a UIButton.

```
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType mediaType:(NSString *)mediaType
{
    if (self.capturedMovies.count > 0)
        [self.capturedMovies removeAllObjects];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType])
    {
        [self.imagePickerViewController setupImagePicker:sourceType mediaType:mediaType];

        if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) { // WORKS
            [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
        else if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) { 
        //else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie] || [mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

            if (!self.moviePickerPopoverController) {
                self.moviePickerPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imagePickerViewController.imagePickerController];
            }

            UIView *uiViewObject = self.mediaTitleTextField;

            CGFloat xLocation = uiViewObject.frame.origin.x;
            CGFloat yLocation = uiViewObject.frame.origin.y;

            CGFloat width = uiViewObject.bounds.size.width;
            CGFloat height = uiViewObject.bounds.size.height;

            // CRASHES HERE!!!
            [self.moviePickerPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(xLocation, yLocation, width, height)
                                                               inView:self.view
                                             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                             animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what pops up in the code window:

Thread 1: signal SIGTRAP on line 3:

```
libsystemkernel.dylib`_kill:
0x394e7830: mov r12, #37
0x394e7834: svc #128
0x394e7838: blo 0x394e7850 ; __kill + 32 <<<<<<<<< Thread 1: signal SIGTRAP
0x394e783c: ldr r12, [pc, #4] ; __kill + 24
0x394e7840: ldr r12, [pc, r12]
0x394e7844: b 0x394e784c ; __kill + 28
0x394e7848: ldrdeq r6, r7, [r0], -r12
0x394e784c: bx r12
0x394e7850: bx lr
```

Here is the backtrace from the debugger:

(lldb) bt

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x394e7838 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 8, stop reason = signal SIGTRAP
    frame #0: 0x394e7838 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x001275d4 MyAppName`TFHandleExceptions + 992
    frame #2: 0x36bd357e CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 614
    frame #3: 0x39313a64 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 128
    frame #4: 0x3363c07a libc++abi.dylib`safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 78
    frame #5: 0x3363c114 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 20
    frame #6: 0x3363d598 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 88
    frame #7: 0x393139d0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 12
    frame #8: 0x36b19f20 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
    frame #9: 0x36b19d48 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #10: 0x38ca82ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 74
    frame #11: 0x3701d300 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120
    frame #12: 0x000629b0 MyAppName`main + 96 at main.m:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575058/1074338

Also, I should have touched the go button on the debugger...
which revealed the offending code:

[image]

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation',
 reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation
 with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```