# how to use UIImagePickerController in an app which support Landscape orientation only in iOS-6?

Tags: ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing an app which supports Landscape orientation only. It uses an `UIImagePickerController` to pick images and/or videos from the library. App is functioning fine in iOS-5 or before but it gets crashed when I try to present image picker controller.It gives the following message after crashing:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468335/ios7-ipad-landscape-only-app-using-uiimagepickercontroller/20468336#20468336

Answer (score 8):

As @rocky said you have to add Potrait mode to your application to use `UIImagePickerController` Like this

[image: Supported Interface Orientation in Info.plist]
or 
add this to your landscape only app delegate class

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and from [**Mr.Daniel's Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575058/1059705) i found a nice solution for your Landscape only App,
as you need to support only landscape to your application, you just need to add a category for `UINavigationController` like this

```
@implementation UINavigationController (LandscapeOnly)

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
@end
```

and add this to your viewControllers, it works for me.

Comment: Did you know if still works for iOS 7? I try to do this, but UIImagePickerCtrler does not show in Landscape mode.

Comment: i have not tested that in iOS 7 so far.. will let you know asap @NorbertoBenavides

Comment: @BetoBens Kindly take a look at this link [Image Picker in Landscape App](https://devforums.apple.com/message/890895#890895), Might help you

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bala, but if I don't misunderstand, the answer makes a UIImagePicker subclass and Apple does not recommend. I decide to use a popover in IPAD version of my app, but in iphone version I couldn't make landscape orientation yet.

Answer (score 2):

From UIImagePickerController documentation:

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

You will have to add Portrait mode to your Support interface orientations if you want to use this controller.