# Not able to open UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am using this code in my button action function:

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am implementing the delegate also. `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

But it gets crashed at
 `[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];`

Can som one help me out on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? you're probably missing something. Add an Exception Breakpoint if you haven't done so already

Comment: use this [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES]; instead of [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: are you using this on ipad?

Comment: @prasad - I am using iPod.

Comment: @Talha - Even after using [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES]; its the same.

Comment: can you please post the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147625/unable-to-get-presentviewcontroller-to-work if you check this link according to this if we are presenting viewcontroller from viewDidLoad method of a rootViewController this crash occurs, but still it will be better if you provide crash details so more peoples can help you.

Comment: if you are app supports only Landscape.. then this link could solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763016/1059705

Comment: did you add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate` in `.h`?

Comment: use like this,  `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES ];`

Comment: @Bala - Thanks. Your comment helped me, although the link did not helped.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is for IOS 6. These delegate methods are supported only in IOS 6.
I got the answer to my own question. My application was developed for landscape mode only. So the imagePickerView was not able to present itself as its default orientation is landscape. So I made my application supported for landscape and portrait mode. In the app delegate I used the method,

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
else  /* iphone */
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

And in the rootViewController I used the following delegates to force the viewController to be in landscape mode and remain in landscape mode.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

}
```

And it worked.