# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in ios6

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using `UIImagePickerviewController` to open the photo library through the below attached code... after called  bit lines of code. The application was crashed... Its working fine in `ios5`

```
UIImagePickerController* content = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
content.delegate = self;
content.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:content animated:YES];
[content release];
```

Is anything wrong with this code?

Comment: I had this issue a few days ago as well, let me check how I fixed it.

Comment: I think it had something to do with autolayout. Do you have autolayout enabled on the view where you are putting the uiimagepicker on?

Comment: Oh, and shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation is depricated in ios6:
Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead.

Comment: i have followed as you given the procedure but nothing will happen

my code is here instead of using   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

Answer (score 0):

Check [Crash on presenting UIImagePickerController under ios6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522491/crash-on-presenting-uiimagepickercontroller-under-ios6) You will get everything you need to make `UIImagePickerviewController` working on iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
  popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
  [popover presentPopoverFromRect:cameraButton.frame inView:self.view  
  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
else{
 [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Because the `UIImagePicker` shows on portrait mode.
I fixed it by subclassing the `UIImagePicker` and implementing the `shouldAutorotate` method like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

I have created instance of my subclassed imagePicker instead of `UIImagePicker`, everything worked fine. Hope this will help you.

Comment: finally i got solved this orientation issue and crashing the app through subclass of UIImagePicker and i had included following method

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

Comment: @StalinPusparaj: i din't get the +1 :) if it solved your issue. Please accept the answer :)

Comment: in SO we usually say +1 when we put a up vote :) That's why I thought. Ok dude. Anyway  thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Hi It doesn't work for me on ios6. Any idea how can I do it? It still rotates the picker