# UIImagePickerController crashes on launch

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture, ios6.1

I present a viewcontroller to the user with a view that shows a UIButton to record a video.  When the user presses the button, my app crashes with the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'

My app only supports portrait orientation and the info.plist file reflects properly.  I use the same code in another app, found on Ray Wenderlich's site, and it works great.  The code for the .h and .m files is below.  Any help would be appreciated.

**.h**

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface RecordSwingViewController: UIViewController

-(BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
                                 usingDelegate:(id )delegate;
-(void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo;



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *record;
- (IBAction)recordSwing:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "RecordSwingViewController.h"

@interface RecordSwingViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecordSwingViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)recordSwing:(id)sender {
    [self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];

}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}



-(BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
                                 usingDelegate:(id )delegate {
    // 1 - Validattions
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil)) {
        return NO;
    }
    // 2 - Get image picker
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    // 3 - Display image picker
    [controller presentViewController: cameraUI animated: YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self,
                                                @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }
    }
}

-(void)video:(NSString*)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Video Saving Failed"
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video Saved" message:@"Saved To Photo Album"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the answer, finally.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570501/2133494
Basically I needed to add a category to my UIImagePickerController.  I tried a lot of other fixes but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented the bool for autorotation, but did not specify if it does not auto rotate what else it should do. Try the following after autorotate method.

```
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft   | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
 }
```

Please remove any of the masks you don't need from the method above and see if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I am still getting the error I tried with the code added, and all of it commented out and there is no change.  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait  ;
}