# xcode iOS6 orientation landscape

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios6, orientation

I see a lot of questions about this subject but am unable to find a solution to the problem I am experiencing. I have created an iPad app that should be Landscape only - it works fine when ran on any os prior to iOS6 but on iOS6 the app opens in portrait view. This screenshot shows what I mean (sorry not a great explanation) http://s1342.beta.photobucket.com/user/designedbyria/media/ScreenShot2012-11-02at122113.png.html

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the below code, but I can't be sure. I have set the supported Interface Orientations to Landscape Left and Landscape Right only - but this has not worked. I have also taken a look at the questions here with no luck..

I am using xcode and cordova/phonegap

[Interface orientation in iOS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404556/interface-orientation-in-ios-6-0)

[Set orientation to landscape mode in xcode 4.5 GM IOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600082/set-orientation-to-landscape-mode-in-xcode-4-5-gm-ios-6)

[iOS 6 apps - how to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/ios-6-apps-how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size/12397738#12397738)

Thanks in Advance!

> > /**
> >          * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here.     (preferred - iOS4 and up)
> >          */
> >        - (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
> >         NSURL* url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
> >         NSString* invokeString = nil;
>
> ```
> if (url && [url isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
>     invokeString = [url absoluteString];      NSLog(@"iwill launchOptions = %@", url);
> }    
>
> CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
> self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
> self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
>
> CGRect viewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
>
> self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
> self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
> self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
> self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
> self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;
> self.viewController.view.frame = viewBounds;
>
> // check whether the current orientation is supported: if it is, keep it, rather than forcing a rotation
> BOOL forceStartupRotation = YES;
> UIDeviceOrientation curDevOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
>
>
> if (UIDeviceOrientationUnknown == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
>     // UIDevice isn't firing orientation notifications yet… go look at the status bar
>     curDevOrientation = (UIDeviceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
> }
>
> if (UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(curDevOrientation)) {
>     for (NSNumber *orient in self.viewController.supportedOrientations) {
>         if ([orient intValue] == curDevOrientation) {
>             forceStartupRotation = YES;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> } 
>
> if (forceStartupRotation) {
>     NSLog(@"supportedOrientations: %@", self.viewController.supportedOrientations);
>     // The first item in the supportedOrientations array is the start orientation (guaranteed to be at least Portrait)
>     UIInterfaceOrientation newOrient = [[self.viewController.supportedOrientations objectAtIndex:0]
> ```
>
> intValue];
>           NSLog(@"AppDelegate forcing status bar to: %d from: %d", newOrient, curDevOrientation);
>           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:newOrient];
>
> ```
> }
>
>
> [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
> [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
>
> return YES; }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (but not using cordova/phonegap).

You have to set your view controller as a RootViewController in your appDelegate instead of just adding as a subview.

Replace in you appdelegate:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

By

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: This way the html goes under the Status Bar. As posted [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1204) you also have to set: `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
}` in MainViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

}
```

Using this delegate and the application will be present in Landscape mode or any desired orientation mode.

Try it.