# iPhone application landscape mode doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Currently I have only portrait mode in iPhone application. I would like to permit landscape mode for one controller in application but unfortunately I'm not able to make it work.

I have these settings in my plist file:

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</array>
```

And I implemented these methods in my controller:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}
```

I use navigation controller in the app so I realize that it might be the problem. I subclassed the `UINavigationController` and implemented again `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` in the same way as above. Of course for I use subclassed navigation controller to show the controller which should have ability to rotate. I also tried to overwrite the methods of navigation controller by category but it also doesn't work.

I don't work on the application from the beginning, I inherited the codes. If there is some possibility how to restrict landscape globally it might be my case. For testing I use iPhone 6.0 simulator but my deployment target is 5.0. I appreciate any tips / help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600082/set-orientation-to-landscape-mode-in-xcode-4-5-gm-ios-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS6 also requires that you set a rootViewController for your window rather than adding the controller's view as a subview.

If you are doing something like this:

```
[window addSubview:someController.view];
```

then you can try changing it to this:

```
[window setRootViewController:someController];
```

Also look at this [link](https://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2012/10/12/handling-autorotation-in-ios-5-and-ios-6-supportedinterfaceorienations-and-shouldautorotate.aspx). For ios6, Apple introduced these two methods :

```
supportedInter
```

1. faceOrientations:
2. shouldAutorotate

Hope it helps.

Shumais Ul Haq

Comment: Thanks a log that was exactly the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this on Controller youwant to give landscape orientation

```
// override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation); // support only landscape
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to target window.
2. Click on Summary tab.
3. iPhone/iPad Deployment info -> Set the supported interface orientations for iPhone & iPad as per your requirement. See following image for more reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Girish but this doesn't help me, I have already set all interface orientations except upside down - exactly as on your screenshot

Comment: @Michal then follow the link shared by Rocks.